# GCP Service Account Credentials Ignored?

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-platform, kubectl

until yesterday I was able to run on GCP an application listening to PubSub and writing data to BigTable, but as of today, I don't seem to have a valid authentication anymore.

Here's how I proceed:

1. I create on the fly a service account:

`gcloud iam service-accounts create ${SERVICE_ACCOUNT} \ 
        --display-name "$(whoami) dev account" --project ${PROJECT_ID}`

2. I create a JSON key file for this account:

`gcloud iam service-accounts keys create  \ 
       "auth-${SERVICE_ACCOUNT}@${PROJECT_ID}.json" --iam-account=${IAM_ACCOUNT} \
       --project ${PROJECT_ID}`

3. I create a `kubectl` key from this JSON file:

`kubectl create secret generic ingester-key \
        --from-file=key.json="auth-${SERVICE_ACCOUNT}@${PROJECT_ID}.json"`

4. I bind this account to admin roles:

`bindings:
- members:
  - serviceAccount:marcello-dev@noisy-turtle-20171031.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  - serviceAccount:service-480932822351@container-engine-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/bigtable.admin
- members:
  - serviceAccount:marcello-dev@noisy-turtle-20171031.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/bigtable.user
- members:
  - serviceAccount:service-480932822351@container-engine-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/container.serviceAgent
- members:
  - serviceAccount:480932822351-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
  - serviceAccount:480932822351@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com
  - serviceAccount:service-480932822351@containerregistry.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/editor
- members:
  - user:marcello@XXXEDITEDXXX
  role: roles/owner
- members:
  - serviceAccount:service-480932822351@container-engine-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/pubsub.admin
- members:
  - serviceAccount:marcello-dev@noisy-turtle-20171031.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/pubsub.editor
- members:
  - serviceAccount:marcello-dev@noisy-turtle-20171031.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/storage.admin
- members:
  - serviceAccount:marcello-dev@noisy-turtle-20171031.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/storage.objectAdmin
- members:
  - serviceAccount:marcello-dev@noisy-turtle-20171031.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/storage.objectCreator
- members:
  - serviceAccount:marcello-dev@noisy-turtle-20171031.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/storage.objectViewer`

5. I get cluster credentials for `kubectl`:

`gcloud container clusters get-credentials ingester-cluster --zone us-east1-b --project noisy-turtle-20171031`

Then I launch the kubernetes cluster (not shown here for brevity), and in the logfile I print out the credentials I am using, to verify that the service account is correct:

`"Account: ServiceAccountCredentials{clientId\u003d117494744145141605372, clientEmail\u003dmarcello-dev@noisy-turtle-20171031.iam.gserviceaccount.com, privateKeyId\u003dad79da59c0a75c2b358d530d63d9a8898523f3cb, transportFactoryClassName\u003dcom.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Utils$DefaultHttpTransportFactory, tokenServerUri\u003dhttps://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token, scopes\u003d[], serviceAccountUser\u003dnull}"`

and find that the clientEmail matches with my service account.

A few cycles later, the application crashes:

`Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Failed to listTables
...
Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Access denied. Missing IAM permission: bigtable.tables.list.`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I found the missing part: after step 2, you need to activate the service account key:

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account ${IAM_ACCOUNT} --key-file="auth-${SERVICE_ACCOUNT}@${PROJECT_ID}.json"
```